# Security of generating hash salts using PHP's mt_rand()?

Tags: php, hash, salt, prng

I'm trying to generate blowfish hashes and I was wondering if it's safe enough to count on [mt_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) to generate my salts for me?

```
function blowfish($string, $salt = NULL, $iterations = '08')
{
    if( ! $salt)
    {
        $seed = "./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        for ($i = 0; $i < 22; $i++)
        {
            $salt .= $seed{mt_rand(0, 63)};
        }
        $salt = '$2a$' . $iterations . '$' . $salt;
    }

    return crypt($string, $salt);
}
```

The character $seed above is the allowed 64-character [blowfish-salt alphabet](https://www.php.net/crypt). I plan on using this to generate and compare passwords.

```
$password = 'my^$%#password';
$hash = blowfish($password);

if($hash = blowfish($password, $hash))
{
    print "Matches\n";
    print $hash . "\n";
}
```

#### Edit

I never realized this, but what @zerkms says is true. Salts are only to prevent reusable  precomputed attacks since the salt is known at the same point that they have access to the hash. So the goal isn't a *non-reversible salt* - it's a **random** salt.

So, anything wrong with this?

```
function blowfish($string, $salt = NULL, $iterations = '12')
{
    return crypt($string, $salt ?: "$2a\$$iterations$" . md5(uniqid('', true)));
}
```

Also, as noted in the title and above code, I'm *not* implementing my own hashing algorithm.

#### Update 2

Using the mcrypt extension if loaded leads to the following, which is actually faster probably because `uniqid` (u)sleeps or something.

```
function blowfish($string, $salt = NULL, $iterations = '12')
{
    return crypt($string, $salt ?: "$2a\$$iterations$" . base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)));
}
```

#### Update 3

base64_encode is faster than md5 - but it has **invalid** blowfish characters in it like `+`. So changed to md5 now.

```
function blowfish($string, $salt = NULL, $iterations = '12')
{
    return crypt($string, $salt ?: "$2a\$$iterations$" . md5(mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)));
}
```

Comment: Salt generation algorithm doesn't matter. What matters is that you have different salts for each password. ps: personally I think your current salt generation is overengineered and I would go with just `md5(uniqid('', true))`

Comment: @pst: Any **real** issues with my advice?

Comment: you could use `$salt = substr(str_shuffle("./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"), -22);` probably quicker..

Comment: ps: seems like there is another programming myth here: about overestimation of the salt generation algorithms.

Comment: @zerkms It means you are letting them know what salts you are using (MD5 of numbers), which in theory means they could precompute attacks. I could create rainbow tables for strings salted with MD5 hashes of 1 through 100000, say. Sure, it's unlikely, but it's conceivable. Truly random is better.

Comment: @Lattyware: "It means you are letting them know what salts you are using" --- so what? Salt is not intended to be secret. "which in theory means they could precompute attacks" --- rainbow tables nowadays are nonsense, CPU is cheaper http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html PS: `uniqid('', true)` is barely predictable and it is not just numbers

Comment: uniqid= numbers and letters and a period 23 characters long

Comment: @zerkms I'm not saying that them knowing the salts is bad, I'm saying that them knowing what salts *everyone* is using is bad. If everyone used your system, the salt becomes useless, just as one salt for your entire database only requires them to recompute the rainbow table once, using the same salts in different databases mean you just compute the rainbow tables you will need. What you say about rainbow tables may be true - but if you are going to do a salt, why not do it right?

Comment: @zerkms I derped and misread your comment, I realise that's not what you meant, so disregard that all XD. Sorry.

Comment: @Lattyware: and what's wrong with my advice? I didn't advice a single salt for the whole database. I could copy-paste my words here, once again: What matters is that you have **different** salts for each password.

Comment: @zerkms Yeah, I get that now, I thought you were suggesting using User IDs, not a random ID - so while different per-user, they would be the same across multiple databases (md5(1) through md5(number of users)). It was my mistake, your suggestion is totally valid.

Comment: @zerkms, can I get any feedback on your md5 approach vs using mcrypt? Everything look good to you?

Comment: @Xeoncross: as I said in my first comment - it doesn't matter how you generate salt, just generate random ones

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [mcrypt](http://docs.php.net/mcrypt_create_iv) to create a salt.

Comment: That's a good idea, I can use `MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM` instead of manually opening a connection to `/dev/urandom` and reading from it and then converting it to base64.

Comment: `MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM` opens a connection to `/dev/random` not `/dev/urandom`. `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` do open a connection to `/dev/urandom`.

Answer (score 4):

Using mt_rand for your salt, is secure enough; provided obviously that you utilize a per password different random salt.

However, with that said; nearly any self-implemented password hashing system is insecure. Few individuals are well versed enough to generate and maintain a secure password hashing system. For reference I implore you to read over a few SO threads:

[Php/Password best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

[Salt generation and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645161/salt-generation-and-open-source-software/1645190#1645190)

[Do not roll your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9985430/1209423)

I suggest **DO NOT ROLL YOUR OWN**. Period. Please look into using the established library of [PhPass of password hashing](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) for PHP if possible. Benefits include real-world application testing, highly secure implementation, and extreme ease of use.

Comment: +1 Security take a lot of time and skill to do right. Why not take advantage of those who have made the mistakes before you have?

Comment: "self-implemented password hashing system is insecure" --- I don't see self-implemented hashing there, do I?

Comment: @PenguinCoder, I'm not rolling my own password hashing - I'm using the tried-and-true blowfish algorithm built into PHP. I just want to know if I can use 22x `mt_rand()` for creating the salts.

Comment: @pst: do you have anything **real** against md5 + uniqid for *generating salt*?

Comment: @pst He isn't suggesting MD5ing the password, he's suggesting MD5 hashing the user ID to generate a salt, rather than generating it randomly.

Comment: @pst, I've only read about theoretical problems and a couple collisions with sha1. I can't imagine that it's actually broken yet - just that it's better to *play it safe* and keep moving to SHA2 and SHA3 when it comes out. Actually, since they are so fast that's why I use blowfish with higher iterations anyway.

Comment: @Lattyware: I didn't suggest hashing user's ID. Please read my comments once again

Comment: @pst: salt is not intended to be secret thing. And if attacker has both salt and hash - it doesn't matter what algorithm has been used to generate it, because what only matters is the salt value

Comment: @pst: how hashing algorithm is related to **salt generation** algorithm? As long as both salt and hash known to the attacker - it doesn't matter where the salt came from - it wouldn't protect from bruteforce

Comment: @pst: I didn't suggest that, I could even copy-paste my advice once again:  I would go with just `md5(uniqid('', true))`

Comment: @pst: salt generation algorithm doesn't matter - the only thing that matters is that result salt is random. I'm sorry, but I'm being boring discussing such trivial things

Comment: @zerkms My mistake, misread what you meant. I was halfway there.

Comment: Hehe, that explains everything :-) Sorry if in some comments my words were a bit rude

Comment: @zerkms No worries, you were completely right. It's always annoying when you can't get someone to understand what you mean, and I was at fault.